# I would like to publish stram using the api-graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

The application has the `publish_stream` permission, but how to make this code using the Graph API?

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'name',
     link: 'link',
     picture : 'image',
     caption: 'caption',
     description : 'description',
     message: '',
     display:'iframe',
properties: {
    'Video name' : { 'text': 'alksdlkjslk', 'href': 'asdasdasd' },
    'Shared From' : { 'text': 'asdadasd', 'href': 'asdasdasd' },

}
   });
```

Comment: I think it's posible to do that , but with curl function .. !!! but how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Publish using graph api, should send a post request. Like this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php   
$access_token = "xxxx";

$fields = "message=test&access_token=$token";

$c = curl_init("http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed");
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);

$r = curl_exec($c);
print_r($r);
```

If not works please let me know...